# Sitecore File Explorer converting Fields <sc:text to <iframe>

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I was trying to upload a sublayout using Sitecore File Explorer.
I see my Sitecore Fields

```xml
 <sc:text id="myId" runat="server" Field="myField"/>
```

in HTML is converted to

```xml
<iframe contenteditable="false" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" onbeforeeditfocus="javascript:event.cancelbubble=true;event.returnvalue=false;return false" border="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" style="display: inline; height: 52px; width: 108px;" src="/sitecore/shell/default.aspx?xmlcontrol=idehtmleditorcontrol&amp;tagprefix=sc&amp;tagname=fieldrenderer&amp;parameters=field%3ddeal%20title%26id%3dscdealtitle&amp;sc_live=0&amp;sc_datasource=%7b110d559f-dea5-42ea-9c1c-8a5df7e70ef9%7d" id="67827f78f3d248ecb5adb7063520f4e0"></iframe>
```

tags in Design Mode.

Most importantly my NEW HTML/markup for the sublayout is not rendering on the page.

Please suggest any Information on how to work with this issue.

Comment: Did you assign the new sublayout to the presentation of the item?

Comment: This is an existing sublayout and checked Overwrite existing files while uploading. I corrected my question saying that New HTML changes are not showing on the page. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Do you have a seperated CMS and CDS Server when using the Sitecore File Explorer on CMS they files are not automatically sync with the CDS.

Comment: I assume the content of the MyField is not the HTML for the iFrame?

Comment: yes, We have separate CM and CD servers. Files are not in Sync.
Thank You @JanBluemink for pointing this out and that is why New Markup is not included on page.

Comment: No @jRobbins I am assuming the Developer Center is somehow converting it only while Viewing. Its is not altering the File on the server. So I am in good shape with it.